# 1) suppress pagebreak between index entry and subentry 2) first and last entry in page header

Tags: indexing

I am using `makeid` on documentclass `book`. The resulting index is fine, but page breaks occur between a main entry and subentries. A subentry may occur as an orphan at the top of page/column, and a main entry may occur without any subentry at the bottom of a page. How do you retain the main entry at the top of a page (or column)?

The second question is how to get the first and last indexentry in the page into the header, on left and right side?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please ask one question only in a question.  Can you show us a small, compilable code (minimal working example) that shows your problem? Or add an screenshot? Better both ...

Comment: To answer question 1 you could add something like this to preamble:\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subitem{\@idxitem\nobreak\hspace*{20\p@}}
\makeatother